# How to get file path from image in ImageView?

Tags: java, android, image, camera

I'm trying to get the file path of an image from ImageView. I have tried numerous implementations using the ones I have seen on StackOverFlow but each has failed. What is wrong with the current implementation I'm using? I'm using Android 7.0 in Android Studio. My code breaks on the line:

```
String pathToImage = pathURI.getPath();
```

This is all my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPUTRE = 1;
ImageView mainImage;
private Uri mImageCaptureUri;

private static final String TAG = "JoelMessage";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button cameraBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cameraBtn);
    mainImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImage);

    //Disable the button if user has no camera
    if(!hasCamera())
        cameraBtn.setEnabled(false);

}

//Check if use has a camera
private boolean hasCamera(){
    return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);

}

//Launching the camera
public void launchCamera(View view){
    //intent to launch camera
    Log.i(TAG, "camera launched");
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);


    //Take picture and pass results along to onActivity Result
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPUTRE);
}

//If you want to return the image taken.



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // request code makes sure u got an image and resultCode makes sure that u got no errors
    if (requestCode  == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPUTRE && resultCode== RESULT_OK ){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data"); //get photo info and storing it in photo

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
        image.setImageBitmap(photo);
        Log.i(TAG, "set image");
        //Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(x));


        //String pathToImage = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();

        // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
        Uri pathURI = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);


        String pathToImage = pathURI.getPath();

        //System.out.println(mImageCaptureUri);


        photo = imageOreintationValidator(photo, pathToImage);

        mainImage.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    return cursor.getString(idx);
}
}
```

Edit
I'm very new to Android development so I'm having difficulty which part of the error messages matter but here are the errors I'm getting that I think are significant:

```
05-10 01:15:56.411 17924-17924/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.example.webbj.cameratest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:73)
```

Feel free to comment if you need more error messages.

Comment: what exception/error are you getting?

Comment: I edited my original post.